# Appointment System, Making Reservation in a sql transaction

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions

I am going to make an appointment system. There is still one question in my mind.

The common requirement is to avoid duplicate booking of the same slot for this kind of system. My question is the actual way to implement this.

Suppose I am going to do the booking part logic within an transaction (with its isolation level set to serializable), my proposed procedures would be:
1. Select data of current booking status.
2. Check if the slot is free to book. If yes, reserve the slot by doing insertion. If not, reserve other slot (with some logic behind for picking other slots).

My questions is, should I place a "XLock" in step 1 to avoid other transactions to know the booking status before the current transaction finished?

Because it seems that placing select with xlock is rare and introduce deadlocks. It could probably slow down the system. (This is what I researched from Web).

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I believe you should be able to do a BEGIN/COMMIT TRANS (with SERIALIZABLE isolation perhaps?). Pretty much any locking is going to slow down the system, but at the benefit of data integrity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Because for what I read from web, it says SERIALIZABLE would place HOLDLOCK onto all SELECT statements. And it seems HOLDLOCK would not block other transactions from doing SELECT statements. I wonder would there be more than one transaction would see the same booking status (although they will be locked in subsequent insertion).